# Defning Django admin models inside subdirectories instead of admin.py

Tags: python, django, django-admin

My goal is to define admin models in separate files. So the project structure looks like this:

app

```
admin_models
       __init__.py
       TestAdmin.py
```

TestAdmin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from cms.models import (
    TestModel)


class TestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = (...)


admin.site.register(TestModel, TestAdmin)
```

The problem is that the model does not appear on the admin page. However, in standard structure (if I move `TestAdmin.py` file's content to `admin.py` on the top level inside the app) then everything works fine. Anyway to fix this?

Comment: Why do you want to call the package `admin_models`?  There are no models inside.

Comment: I don't want to call it. Actually, I just want to see my admin model appear in the Django admin's page.

Comment: :) Again. I am unsure what you mean by "admin model"?  i assume you are talking about model admins.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Sorry for messing up terms )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django's internals (e.g. the ["autodiscovery"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#discovery-of-admin-files)) rely on a certain app structure. Part of that is that the `admin` namespace within an installed app is imported at app loading time (in the [`AppConfig.ready`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready) method). So you can make a package structure like:

```
app
    admin
        __init__.py
        test_admin.py  # different from admin class name!
        another_admin.py
```

In your `test_admin.py` you define your `TestAdmin` class as you have before. And in the package's `__init__.py`, you import the admins from the submodules:

```
# __init__.py
from .test_admin import TestAdmin
from .other_admin import YetAnotherAdmin
```

That way, you can structure your code base and django's internal working will still register the model admins as they are in the place where it's looking for them.

As pointed out by @Alasdair, you can also "manually" import your custom admin modules in a custom AppConfig. If you don't already have one, I would stick with the above described method as it doesn't require changes in various places (`INSTALLED_APPS` or `app/__init__.py`, `app/apps.py`, ...) that could have unforeseen side effects.

Comment: To add to this, the 'autodiscovery' of the `admin.py` files happens because you include the [`AdminConfig`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.apps.AdminConfig) in your `INSTALLED_APPS`. So another approach would be to use your own config class to imported/register your model admin classes.